# Factor Analysis in python

Tags: python, analysis, factor-analysis

is there a module that contains a function that calculate Factor Analysis (not PCA)
in python?

Answer (score 5):

Here is the [direct link](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net/node_list.html#mdp.nodes.FANode) to the MDP Factor Analysis node.
The MDP homepage is [here](http://mdp-toolkit.sourceforge.net).

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is http://pypi.python.org/pypi/MDP/2.3. First result in Google on query *Factor Analysis python* ;-)